# handler for a submit button

Tags: forms, extjs, handler

I want to use a save button with a form in extjs. This is what i have as a handler

```
{
         xtype: 'button',
         handler: function(button, event) {
             var form = this.getForm();
             if (form.isValid()) {
                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Submitted Values', form.getValues(true));
                                 }
                                           },
          height: 37,
          id: 'configurationDriversSave',
          text: 'Save'
}
```

All i get now in firebug is an error: this.getForm is not a function. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the handler `this` will be reference to the button itself. You can check that in firebug, button of course doesn't have method `getForm()`. You need to call something like 'this.up('form')`.

Second thing - you don't have to do manual validation like you are trying to do. ExtJs has built-in validation mechanism for the forms.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getForm
```

is not supported in Firefox,
use `document.forms` instead,
Or you can get any reference from this [link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-9215.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-all-form-objects.phtml), you can simply use `this.form` to access the form element that contains the element that generated the event.

So, instead of

```
var form = this.getForm();
```

use

```
var form = this.form;
```